# How to add/remove line series dynamically in androidplot?

Tags: legend, visibility, androidplot, lineseries

I am using the `androidplot` for charts. I want to show/hide line series dynamically like the `Scichart`does where user can check or uncheck the legend and corresponding renderable line series will show or hide on graph.

Comment: If you can provide us with the code you worked upon, we can help you in a better way.

Comment: @Himanshu Bansal i have not write the code yet. I was just researching the above mentioned problem on androidplot official website. I could not find the solution over there.

Comment: If you can't find it. Make it :) and if you still have trouble making it. We are here to help you with that logic.